# How to rename VBA template name in ribbon of ms-word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using VBA template(.dotm) in ms-word. I want to rename the template name(name that appear on ms-word ribbon after attaching the template). I want to rename SCAT to ABC.

[image]

Project Files:

[image]

Comment: Did you create this template? If not, do you know whether this is a VBA template or a VSTO project? Changing the **tab caption** requires changing the underlying Ribbon XML. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: @Cindy. No I didn't create this template. It is a VBA project. I am new to VBA so I don't have any experience of Ribbon XML. I am updating the image of project files. Please see and guide me.

Comment: OK, to get you started, you should read (at least) the first part of Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12) to get some basic understanding of the technology. I recommend you concentrate on the sections "General Format of XML Markup Files" and "Customizing the Fluent UI by Using Office Open XML Formats Files". This is only to give you a basic understanding - you don't need to actually *do* any of this.

Comment: Then you need the Custom UI Editor Tool to open the template and make the change to the label. You can download it here https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm (also read this article). There are instructions for using it here https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-customize-the-excel-2016-ribbon-with-xml/. Don't worry that this is written for Excel, that doesn't matter. It shows how to open a document and edit the underlying Ribbon XML. All you need to do is find that tab and change the label - the text between the "" (be sure to not delete the quotes).

Comment: Great :-) Glad you were able to follow all that documentation!